# How to introduce random noise in the kernel of Training Op in TensorFlow?

Tags: kernel, tensorflow, normal-distribution

I tried to improve one of the optimizer `RMSPropOptimzer`, by injecting random noise following normal distribution. So I attempted to directly rebuild the source file of [tensorflow\core\kernels\training_ops.cc](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/core/kernels/training_ops.cc), specifically rewriting the algorithm of `ApplyRMSProp`.

Therefore, I tried to introduce random noise. I find that there is a [RandomUniform](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/core/kernels/random_op.cc#L509) in the kernel file `random_op.cc`, which seems to generate normal distribution. But I do not know how to invoke that interface in the kernel file of `training_ops.cc`. So I ask if someone can give me any advice on how to introducing random variable into Training Op.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried to call the `random_uniform` function in my optimizer, by `from tensorflow.python.ops import random_ops`, such that a tensor containing random variables are fed to training Op. And it is resolved.